# JQuery tablesorter appended data not sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Im trying too append data to a table with the tablesorter plugin (http://tablesorter.com)
Im using the following code:

```
<table id="sortme" border="1" style="width: 200px;">             
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>age</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>will</td>
          <td>smith</td>
          <td>1</td>
      </tr> 
...................
</tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" id="test">Click me!</a>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var i = 5;
 $("#sortme").tablesorter({
     sortList: [[2,0]]         
 }); 
 $("#test").click(function() {
     $("#sortme tbody").append('<tr><td>NEW</td><td>NEW</td><td>'+(i++)+'</td></tr>');
     $("#sortme").trigger("update");
     var s = [[2,0]];
     $("#sortme").trigger("sorton",[s]);
     return false;
 });
});
```

Problem is the appended row stays at top, why?
See example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmU3Z/8/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're problem is the `[s]`. You're sort parameter is already an array, just pass it the var not the var in an array.

```
$("#sortme").trigger("sorton",s);
```

Works for me, FF4.

Comment: Works but generates a error:
[1] is undefined
http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.js
Row: 573

Comment: I think I found it. In the tablesorter construct, they call `buildHeaders` to get a list of columns they can sort, then `buildCache` to sort against. When you call an update, it only builds the cache (instead of re-instantiating the table). Maybe this is a bug or an undocumented feature. At any rate, re-calling the construct [as seen in the newest version](http://jsfiddle.net/jmU3Z/14/) will have it re-build the cache and sort properly. Also most likely worth mentioning to the creator. ;-)

Comment: Yeah that works, but not so pretty =/
Well its a solution, and no so hard too patch the update code. Thanks

Comment: This answer **IS WRONG** in two ways. (1) The plugin is expecting a nested array, so the `s` in the trigger DOES need to be wrapped - see [this example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html). (2) The demo shared in the comments re-initializes the plugin a second time so clicking on a header to sort will end up sorting the table twice, restoring it to it's original sort. Initialize it again, it will sort 3x, etc. Try this [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/jmU3Z/42/) (updated to link to the tablesorter plugin and add comments).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles across this.

By the time the "sorton" event is handled the DOM hasn't been assigned the table.config.parsers. The "sorton" event handling needs to be wrapped in a 1 millisecond timeout.

Replace the existing "sorton" bind in jquery.tablesorter.js (line ~803) with the following:

```
}).bind("sorton", function (e, list) {
    var me = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).trigger("sortStart");
        config.sortList = list;
        // update and store the sortlist
        var sortList = config.sortList;
        // update header count index
        updateHeaderSortCount(me, sortList);
        // set css for headers
        setHeadersCss(me, $headers, sortList, sortCSS);
        // sort the table and append it to the dom
        appendToTable(me, multisort(me, sortList, cache));
    }, 1);
```