# Google Maps data not being read in by jQuery .tablesorter()

Tags: google-maps, tablesorter

I'm using Google Maps to calculate distances between a user-entered address and our store locations.  Once this data is read in, I'd like to use jQuery .tablesorter() to sort the table from closest to furthest store.  However, the data read in from Google Maps is not being recognized by the jQuery .tablesorter() function.  I tried implementing the setTimeout() suggestion on this thread ([JQuery tablesorter appended data not sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539616/jquery-tablesorter-appended-data-not-sorting)) and numerous other fixes that did not work.  I understand what's happening (the DOM not recognizing data written to the page after it's been constructed), but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Here's the URL to the test page if you'd like to see what's happening:  http://www.gregcklotz.com/Larry/Locations.php

Comment: There are two errors inside the console, the first related to the fact, that you have included the Maps-API multiple times. Please fix this first.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the table after adding all of the distance data into the columns:

```
for (i = 0; i < stores.length; i++)
{
    address = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    coords = new google.maps.LatLng(stores[i].lat, stores[i].long);
    distance = (.621371192237334 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(address, coords)/1000).toFixed(1);
    $("tr.store"+stores[i].store+" td:last").text(parseInt(distance));
}
// update the table data
$("table").trigger("update");
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```